# Some Truffle Commands do nothing

Tags: npm, solidity, node-gyp, smartcontracts, truffle

So Ive been dealing with a very odd problem that seems to have happened out of nowhere. My truffle compile, test, and migrate commands do literally nothing. However my other commands like develop, networks, console etc work properly. When I type truffle migrate in the console this happens:
[Nothing happens and the the terminal line just goes to a new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EynMt.png)

And this is what happens when I run truffle develop: 
[Works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deZkr.png)

I did the same withh an out of the box drizzle app. Its config file looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
// to customize your Truffle configuration!
contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "app/src/contracts"),
solc: {
  optimizer: {
    enabled: true,
    runs: 200
  }
},
networks: {
  development: {
    host: "LOCALHOST",
    port: 8545,
    network_id: "5777", // Match any network id
  }
}};
```

And the migration file looks like this:

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");
const TutorialToken = artifacts.require("TutorialToken");
const ComplexStorage = artifacts.require("ComplexStorage");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage);
  deployer.deploy(TutorialToken);
  deployer.deploy(ComplexStorage);
};
```

Everything looks fairly normal and I cant seem to figure out what the problem is. Apps that used to work before, now cant seem to run truffle compile, migrate or test commands.

So I initially thought it might be a problem with my npm packet or maybe requires a new update. So I uninstalled and reinstalled truffle@latest. I started noticing I was getting a specific error sometimes when i download certain packages:

```
/Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/truffle -> 
/Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js

> keccak@1.4.0 install /Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
> npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."


> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild /Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node" "/Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/aditya/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v11.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.
+ truffle@5.0.5
added 91 packages from 305 contributors in 7.797s
```

This node-gyp error kept showing up numerous times when installing specific packages. So I did a complete overhaul of my npm, by uninstalling and reinstalling npm. This changed nothing and this error still keeps on showing up. Im not sure if this error has anything to do with the Truffle command problem.

Comment: How about Truffle v4? Probably v5/latest doesn't work with your environment.

Comment: use sudo gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied,

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, turned out it was a permission problem.

```
sudo truffle migrate
```

Works

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer, but i am posting for newcommers, here the issue might be with the ownership of a directory, so
To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory

On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

```
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

add this line:

```
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

On the command line, update your system variables:

```
 source ~/.profile
```

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

```
 npm install -g node-gyp
```